# Typhoon swap assembly for UI testing

Tags: swift, ui-testing, typhoon

Is it possible to swap or patch an assembly when running a UI test on iOS? Currently I have a project where I have setup Typhoon framework and I am able to patch an assembly like this

```
var controller: HomeViewController!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // setup assemblies
    var blAssembly = BusinessLogicAssembly()
    var ctrlAssembly = AppAssembly()

    // setup patcher
    let patcher = TyphoonPatcher()
    patcher.patchDefinitionWithSelector("testManager", withObject: {return FakeManager()})

    patcher.patchDefinition(blAssembly.testManager() as TyphoonDefinition, withObject: {
        return FakeManager()})


    let factory = TyphoonBlockComponentFactory(assemblies: [blAssembly, ctrlAssembly])
    factory.attachPostProcessor(patcher)


    // get controller
    controller = factory.componentForKey("homeViewController") as HomeViewController

    // force view to laod
    let vcView = controller.view
}
```

And this is working fine. It patches the `TestManager` with a stub. But in this case I am manually invoking my view controller. When I run a UI test (where the controllers are handled behind the scenes when the app is launched) is there a way of patching an assembly and providing a mock/stub?

For instance lets say I have a view controller which is calling a web service. The web service logic is wrapped in a separate class and is injected into the view controller with a `TyphoonAssembly`. Now for my UI tests I do not want to contact my actual web services but just proved sample data. I am imagining doing this by creating a stub of my web service class and returning test data. Can this be achieved with the Typhoon framework because I was unable to do it or find an example anywhere.

I am using Swift but Objective-C answers will work too (as long as it is compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there's a few ways with Typhoon that one component can be swapped for another. We could use [TyphoonPatcher](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Integration-Testing#patching-out-a-component) or [modularize assemblies](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Modularizing-Assemblies). Or we could even make a custom [TyphoonDefinitionPostProcessor](http://typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/protocol_typhoon_definition_post_processor-p.html) or TyphoonInstancePostProcessor.

**The problem/solution:**

But if I'm understanding your question correctly, the problem is that application-style  (default) kind of tests are being used, where:

- The TEST_HOST flag is set. Your application classes are visible to your tests.
- **Integration tests instantiate their own assembly, rather than use the application assembly.** While this is normally recommended, its important to be aware that this is ***a separate, additional*** assembly to the one used in the main app.

If you want to modify the main app's assembly from tests, we can use `defaultFactory`. If you're using plist integration:

**Create a definition for you app delegate:**

```
 dynamic func appDelegate() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
        (definition) in

        //This is a public instance var of type TyphoonComponentFactory
        definition.injectProperty("assembly", with: self)
    }
}
```

. . and then in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    factory.makeDefault()

}
```

. . . now in your tests or wherever you need, you patch the app's assembly, by getting a hook to it:

```
TyphoonComponentFactory *factory = [TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory];
[factory unload]; //clear out any singletons
//Now patch it
```

- Note that you may need to call `factory.unload()` to clear any instances of `TyphoonScopeSingleton` before-hand.
- Also note that TyphoonPatcher also allows unpatching or winding back if you wish.

**Alternative:**

Alternatively, and simpler (we recommend simple wherever possible), perhaps you could just start up the app with a different network assembly specifying a different set of assemblies in the application plist.

*NB: In Objective-C any `TyphoonComponentFactory` can be cast to an Assembly and vice-versa. This is not allowed in Swift, so might create some inconvenient limitations. To be addressed by [#253](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/253)

Comment: Could you explain to me what do you mean by starting the app with a different network assembly?

Comment: I mean that if you **modularize assemblies** (see link above) then you can provide an alternative implementation at start-up. So instead of a Network assembly that makes real client calls, you can provide one that just stubs. You can do this by overriding or just provide one a different implementation. So if your Network assembly produces one top-left component called 'client', then provide a new assembly that returns also returns a 'client', but this time a stub. Collaborating assemblies are just a contract, and we provide the actual list that will be used to Typhoon at startup.

Comment: Is this achievable using Plist activation? Because I tried deriving from my actual assembly and override the method that provides the implementation and then in the Tests target's Info.plist I specify the stub assembly but it on startup the actual assembly is used

Comment: plist bootstrapping is only (intentionally) supported for the main app target. modularization is supported in that you can provide whatever list of assemblies you want for the main target's plist. If you want this to be dynamic you could perhaps a) Duplicate the main target, provide a different plist b) Add a shell script to the *build phase" of your target that copies the plist over (perhaps based on a UI_TEST flag c) etc

Comment: Is there a documented example of how to bootstrap your app with different implementation of an assembly for different targets using manual activation. Because all I see in the github wiki is saying that it is possible but not an example of how to do it and I am failing to do it on my own

Comment: Are you clear that changing the assembly used in your tests won't affect your app? (For XCTest based tests that is). Your app has a different instance of TyphoonComponentFactory. . . We don't have documentation for that specific scenario but you could refer to the a typhoon test cases. By the way have you looked at the sample app? https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon-Swift-Example . . Try replacing the network client there for one that returns s stub and run the app.

Comment: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/blob/master/Tests/Factory/Block/BlockComponentFactory/TyphoonBlockComponentFactory_OverridingTests.m

Comment: What do you mean by not going to affect my app? That is what I am trying to achieve when I run the application in a test and for example click on a button that normally fetches data from a server to just provide some hardcoded data. I've been looking into the example app and it doesn't seem to have any application-style tests where UI interaction is involved and the whole application is being bootstrapped

Comment: Can you read the answer again? I edited to try to make it more clear. a) When you bootsrap Typhoon in your tests that's not the Typhoon used by the app b) If you want to modify the Typhoon used by the app you have to get a hook to it using `defaultFactory` . . clear now?

Comment: So I am trying to patch the factory the same way I have shown in my post but instead of instantiating a new factory I use `TyphoonComponentFactory.defaultFactory()` but still the original implementation used in the test. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, did not follow last comment. Still not working?

Comment: Yes, can you give an example of how to patch the factory because it seems I am doing it wrong